# Runtime Error in HDF5 file manipulation

Tags: c++, hdf5

I was trying a program where I'll convert an array of structures to byte array and then save them to hdf5 dataset multiple times. (Dataset has dimension of 100, so Ill do the write operation 100 times). I dont have any problems in converting structure to byte array , I seem to run into problem when I try to select the hyperslab where I need to write data in the dataset. I am new to hdf5. Please help me with this problem.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "h5cpp.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

#ifndef H5_NO_NAMESPACE
    using namespace H5;
#endif

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;

const H5std_string  fName( "dset.h5" );
const H5std_string  dsName( "dset" );

struct MyStruct
{
    int x[1000],y[1000];
    double z[1000];
};


int main()
{
    try
    {
        MyStruct obj[10];
        char* totalData;
        char* inData;
        hsize_t offset[1],count[1];

        H5File file("sample.h5", H5F_ACC_TRUNC);

        StrType type(PredType::C_S1,100*sizeof(obj));

        Group *myGroup = new Group(file.createGroup("\\myGroup"));

        hsize_t dim[] = {100};

        DataSpace dSpace(1,dim);

        DataSet dSet = myGroup->createDataSet("dSet", type, dSpace);

        for(int m = 0; m < 100 ; m++)
        {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++)
            {
                for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++) // some random values stored
                {
                    obj[j].x[i] = i*13 + i*19;
                    obj[j].y[i] = i*37 - i*18;
                    obj[j].z[i] = (i + 1) / (0.4 * i);
                }
            }
            totalData = new char[sizeof(obj)];  // converting struct to byte array
            memcpy(totalData, &obj, sizeof(obj));

            cout<<"Start Write.\n";
            cout<<"Total Size : "<<sizeof(obj)/1000<<"KB\n";

            //Exception::dontPrint();

            hsize_t dim[] = { 1 }; //I think am screwing up between this line and following 5 lines 

            DataSpace memSpace(1, dim);

            offset[0] =  m;
            count[0] = 1;
            dSpace.selectHyperslab(H5S_SELECT_SET, count, offset);

            dSet.write(totalData, type, memSpace, dSpace);

            cout<<"Write Done.\n";
            cout<<"Read Start.\n"; 
            inData = new char[sizeof(obj)];
            dSet.read(inData, type);
            cout<<"Read Done\n";
        }
        delete myGroup;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printError();
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The Output I get is,

[image]

And when I use H5S_SELECT_APPEND instead of H5S_SELECT_SET, the output says

```
Start Write.
Total Size : 160KB
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.12) thread 0:
#000: ..\..\src\H5Shyper.c line 6611 in H5Sselect_hyperslab(): unable to set hyperslab    selection
major: Dataspace
minor: Unable to initialize object
#001: ..\..\src\H5Shyper.c line 6477 in H5S_select_hyperslab(): invalid selection operation
major: Invalid arguments to routine
minor: Feature is unsupported
```

Please, help me with this situation. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the size of your `type` datatype. It should be `sizeof(obj)` and not `100*sizeof(obj)`.

And anyway, you shouldn't be using a string datatype but an *opaque* datatype since that's what it is, so you can replace this whole line by:

```
DataType type(H5T_OPAQUE, sizeof(obj));
```

The second problem is in the `read`. Either you read everything and you need to make sure `inData` is big enough, that is `100*sizeof(obj)` instead of `sizeof(obj)`, or you need to select just the element you want to read just like for the `write`.

Comment: Lets assume that I am not interested in reading and assume that I exclude the read part and just keep on writing data into the file. From your answer, shall I assume that making the following changes will make things work ?                                                    1) Change type statement to DataType type(H5T_OPAQUE, sizeof(obj)); (Please remember that I do the write operation 100 times)            and please mention that is it correct way to do the write operation for this program.

Comment: Yes. Remember that you are building an array with 100 elements, each of size `sizeof(obj)`. In HDF5, datatypes are the type of _one_ element of an array, while _dataspaces_ contain the number of elements.